# Нажать на ссылки delphi

Tags: delphi-7

(Delphi 7, indy)
Без потока программа работает в зависшем состоянии. Попытаюсь с потоком, компилируется . при нажатии на кнопку (access violation on address 0049974c)

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, IdCookieManager, IdIOHandler, IdIOHandlerSocket,
  IdIOHandlerStack, IdSSL, IdSSLOpenSSL, IdBaseComponent, IdComponent,
  IdTCPConnection, IdTCPClient, IdHTTP, ExtCtrls, Unit2;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    IdHTTP1: TIdHTTP;
    IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
    IdCookieManager1: TIdCookieManager;
    Button1: TButton;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    Timer1: TTimer;

    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
   my:myth;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}



procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);

begin
my:=myth.Create(true);
my.Priority:=tpNormal;
my.FreeOnTerminate:=True;
my.Resume;
end;
end.


Поток
unit Unit2;

interface

uses
Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, IdCookieManager, IdIOHandler, IdIOHandlerSocket,
  IdIOHandlerStack, IdSSL, IdSSLOpenSSL, IdBaseComponent, IdComponent,
  IdTCPConnection, IdTCPClient, IdHTTP, ExtCtrls;

type
  myth = class(TThread)
   IdHTTP1: TIdHTTP;
    IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
    IdCookieManager1: TIdCookieManager;
    Button1: TButton;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    Timer1: TTimer;
  private
    { Private declarations }
  protected

    procedure Execute; override;
    procedure meme;
    public

  end;

implementation
   uses Unit1;


procedure myth.Execute;

begin
 Synchronize(meme);
end;

procedure myth.meme;
 var
  s:string; list, lista:TStringList;
  resul: string;
begin
list:=TStringList.Create;
Form1.Memo1.Clear;
list.Add('...');
list.Add('...');
list.Add('...');
list.Add('...');
s:=IdHTTP1.Post('https://,list);
   list.Free;
(АВТОРИЗАЦИЯ)
 resul:=idHTTP1.Get('...');
  while Pos('tdn',resul) > 0 do begin ЖМЕМ НА КНОПКИ
  lista:=TStringList.Create;     lista.Add('...');
IdHTTP1.Post('https:...,lista);
       lista.Free ;
  end;
  end;
end.
```

Comment: Что значит нажать? где код(а не ваши троеточия)?

Comment: Посмотрите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Я мало что понял из вашего кода... суть вопроса например - не понял